# How to Resolve "too_many_total_groups" Error with Amplitude Identify Call Using Segment?

Tags: segment-io, amplitude-analytics

I am encountering an error when trying to use the identify function with Amplitude in combination with Segment. The tracking calls work correctly, but when I use identify, I receive a "too_many_total_groups" error. This issue occurs consistently with identify calls but not with tracking calls.

```
[{"body": "too_many_total_groups","headers": {"access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST","access-control-allow-origin": "*","access-control-max-age": "86400","connection": "close","content-length": "21","content-type": "text/html;charset=utf-8","date": "Mon, 27 Nov 2023 11:36:47 GMT","strict-transport-security": "max-age=15768000","trace-id": "xxxx"},"statusCode": 400,"statusMessage": "Bad Request"}]
```

And here is the Python function I use for the **`identify`** call:

```
def identify(id, email, first_name, last_name):
    user_id = id
    company = parse_company_name(email)
    analytics.identify(
        user_id,
        {
            "email": email,
            "first_name": first_name,
            "lastName": last_name,
            "company": company,
            "created_at": datetime.now(),
        },
    )
```

My questions are:

1. What does the **`"too_many_total_groups"`** error indicate specifically in the context of using **`identify`** with Segment and Amplitude?
2. Are there known limitations or common issues with the **`identify`** function that could lead to this error, and how can I resolve it?

I've tried simplifying the userId to a standard format, and also ensured that my group types and properties are within the limits specified by Amplitude.